# Which svn commands asks for what's new in the trunk?

Tags: svn

Before I execute svn update I'd like to know which files will be affected (which will be modified, which will be added and which will be removed). Looking through the svn commands svn mergeinfo seems the closest, but it requires an argument.

Comment: You can't ever do this reliably, because new commits may be created between the time you look and the time you actually run update.

Comment: @Jan - good point. Still useful command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find

```
svn status -u
```

helpful.

See [svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html)